# How to fix subscribe not exist in type void

Tags: angular7

I am new to angular 7 and didn't find any proper answer for similar questions posted.

I am getting Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void' in angular-cli. I tried importing subscribe from rxjs but didn't find that library.

The problem is in the UpdateRecord Function!

**product.component.ts code:**

the code bellow is exist in compoent.ts of product

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/shared/product.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service : ProductService, private toastr : ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form != null)
      form.resetForm();
    this.service.formData = {
      ProductID: null,
      ProductName: '',
      ProductDescription: '',
      Price: 0.00,
      Image: '',
      Qte: null
    }
  }


  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value.ProductID == null)
      this.insertRecord(form);
    else
      this.updateRecord(form);
  }

  insertRecord(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.postProduct(form.value).subscribe(res => {
      this.toastr.success('Inserted successfully', 'Product. Register');
      this.resetForm(form);
      this.service.refreshList();
    });
  }

  updateRecord(form: NgForm) {
     this.service.putProduct(form.value).subscribe(res => {
       this.toastr.success('Updated successfully', 'Product. Update');
       this.resetForm(form);
      this.service.refreshList();
     });

  }

}
```

**product.service.ts code :**

the code bellow is exist in service file related to product

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product.model';

import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  formData : Product
  list : Product[]
  readonly rootURL= 'http://localhost:50369/api'

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  postProduct(formData : Product){
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL+'/Product', formData);
  }

  refreshList(){
    return this.http.get(this.rootURL+'/Product')
    .toPromise().then(res => this.list = res as Product[]);
  }

  putProduct(formData : Product){
    this.http.put(this.rootURL+'/Product/'+formData.ProductID,FormData);
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: did you try putting a specific type to your put function like this `putProduct(formData : Product): Observable<Product>()`?

Comment: @IanPreglo i tried to do this but it still not work with same issue :/

Comment: did you try changing your body parameter from class to object? like so: `this.http.put(this.rootURL+'/Product/'+formData.ProductID,formData)` (note the small 'f') in the second parameter.

Comment: @IanPreglo can you give me an example !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed return :

So in putProduct function in product.service.ts is updated to be :

```
 putProduct(formData : Product){
    return this.http.put(this.rootURL+'/Product/'+formData.ProductID,FormData);
  }
```

And it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Your HttpClient.put function seems to be incorrectly used (you are passing the class as parameter when you should be passing the object).

Look for the function `updateHero()` in this [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzcrae?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.service.ts).

```js
/** PUT: update the hero on the server. Returns the updated hero upon success. */
  updateHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
    httpOptions.headers =
      httpOptions.headers.set('Authorization', 'my-new-auth-token');

    return this.http.put<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('updateHero', hero))
      );
  }
```